# How can I call UITextField delegate methods in a different Objective-C class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I have a class Temp which stores lots of UITextField. I use another class EditViewController to display these UITextField and I want to call UITextField delegate in EditViewController class. So how can I achieve this?

I already tried below code with no luck.

```
ViewController *viewConnection = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EditViewController"];

tfQue = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, viewLoc.frame.size.width - 90, 25)];
tfQue.placeholder = @"tap here to type description for date";
tfQue.layer.borderWidth = 0;
tfQue.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tfQue.tag = tag;
tfQue.delegate = viewConnection;
```

Above code is written in a function in Temp class. Below is the code to access this function in EditViewController:

```
newElement = [tempObj createTextfieldWithQuestion:strQuestionText withOriginY:posY withIndexTag:i + 1];
[self.view addSubview:newElement];
```

Comment: "I have a class Temp which stores lots of UITextField. I use another class EditViewController to display these UITextField" - why? What's the purpose of storing UI elements outside of the view/view controller?

Comment: I'm working on an app which allows users to create different forms/templates. So I have a common class where I store most of the UI elements provided by Xcode.

Comment: how you are accessing / display  tfQue  textfield in your EditViewController.??

Comment: @HirenPrajapati Then it might make sense to have factory class, but storing instances is pretty absurd.

Comment: @luckyShubhra In EditVC, I call function for creating UI reside in Temp class. I use instant of Temp class and call that function which returns UIView and stored in EditVC's view. See my updated question.

Comment: @mag_zbc I really don't have any idea about factory class. I thought my method was correct. Just to have a separate class for creation of all elements within function which returns UIView to be stored in different class. I add these objects in an array to track. See my updated answer on how I use this function in Edit class.

Comment: How you show `EditViewController` ? Is this pushed or segue ?

Comment: @LalKrishna EditViewController is pushed. But I don't think it would matter here.

Comment: Try `newElement.delegate = self;`

Comment: tempObj createTextfieldWithQuestion returns a textfield, you can assign EditViewController as delegate of textfied, as newElement.delegate = self

Comment: @LalKrishna new element would be UIView, not UITextField as function will return UIView with its subviews consisting of UITextField, UIButton etc.

Comment: can you add code for createTextfieldWithQuestion method??

Comment: Do you add the text field as a subview to EditViewController'z view?

Comment: guys. I have posted solution. Please check out. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Pass self reference to Assign it as TextField Delegate.

```
- (UIView *)createTextfieldWithQuestion:(NSString *)strQuestionText withOriginY:(NSInteger)posY withIndexTag:(NSInteger)indexTag setDelegateForUITextField:(id)delegateParent {
tfQue = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, viewLoc.frame.size.width - 90, 25)];
tfQue.placeholder = @"tap here to type description for date";
tfQue.layer.borderWidth = 0;
tfQue.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
tfQue.tag = tag;
tfQue.delegate = delegateParent;
}
```

Call

```
[tempObj createTextfieldWithQuestion:strQuestionText withOriginY:posY withIndexTag:i + 1 setDelegateForUITextField:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this. Below is the solution.

```
     -(UIView*)createTextfieldWithQuestion: (NSString *)text withOriginY: (CGFloat)posY withIndexTag: (int)tag withTarget:(ViewController *)vc
        {
        UIView *viewLoc = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, posY, SCREEN_WIDTH - 10,   TF_VIEW_HEIGHT)];
        viewLoc.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

        tfQue = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 10, viewLoc.frame.size.width - 90, 25)];
        tfQue.placeholder = @"tap here to type description for date";
        tfQue.layer.borderWidth = 0;
        tfQue.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        tfQue.tag = tag;
        tfQue.delegate = vc;
        ...
        ...
        [viewLoc addSubview:tfQue];

        return viewLoc;
       }
```

Above code is written in a function in Temp class. Below is the code to access this function in EditViewController:

```
newObj = [tFunc createTextfieldWithQuestion:strQuestionText withOriginY:posY withIndexTag:i + 1 withTarget:self];
[self.view addSubview:newElement];
```